# Confirmar senha de registro Ionic 3

Tags: ionic, firebase, typescript, ionic3

Tenho um formulário de registro no Ionic 3, mas eu não consigo fazer validar a senha com um outro ion input.

register.html:

```
<ion-item class = "log-input">
  <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" #username></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item class = "log-input">
  <ion-label floating>Senha</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="password" #password></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item class = "log-input">
  <ion-label floating>Confirmar</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="password" #conf></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Registrar

register.ts

```js
import { Component,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-register',
  templateUrl: 'register.html',
})
export class RegisterPage {
  @ViewChild('username') uname;
  @ViewChild('password') password;
  @ViewChild('password') conf;
  constructor(private alertCtrl:AlertController,private fire:AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad RegisterPage');
  }

  alert(message:string){
    this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Info',
      subTitle:message,
      buttons: ['OK']
    }).present();
  }

  registerUser(){
    this.fire.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.uname.value, this.password.value, this.conf.value)
    .then(data=>{
     console.log("Sucesso",data);
     this.alert('Muito bem! Você está registrado.');
    })
    .catch(error =>{
      console.log('Erro',error);
      this.alert(error);
    })
    console.log("Registro com",this.uname.value , this.password.value);
  }
}
```

Bem quando eu chamo o ''this.conf.value'' no método de criar usuário, ele dá um erro, ''Expected 2 arguments, but got 3''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `this.fire.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` admite apenas dois argumentos (e-mail e senha). Você está tentando adicionar um terceiro que, pelo seu código, também é uma senha. Você não vai conseguir usar esse método com as três informações.

Comment: Pois é. @root se você quiser validar se a senha corresponde à confirmação, faça uma verificação antes de chamar o [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword)